# Powershell - Find path to connected android phone

Tags: android, powershell, windows-7, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that will back up my phones files to my pc. Thus far I have :

```
$phone = gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice | %{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID | Where-Object {$_.Manufacturer -eq "motorola"}
```

Which shows:

```
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&MI_00\\7&287261EF&0&000
                          0"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 24
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                    : MpComp
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\MyComproot\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&MI_0
                          0\\7&287261EF&0&0000"
Availability                : 
Caption                     : XT1039
ClassGuid                   : {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}
CompatibleID                : {USB\MS_COMP_MTP, USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff&Prot_00, USB\Class_ff&SubClas
                          s_ff, USB\Class_ff}
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity
Description                 : XT1039
DeviceID                    : USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&MI_00\7&287261EF&0&0000
ErrorCleared                : 
ErrorDescription            : 
HardwareID                  : {USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&REV_0228&MI_00, USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&MI_00}
InstallDate                 : 
LastErrorCode               : 
Manufacturer                : motorola
Name                        : XT1039
PNPDeviceID                 : USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&MI_00\7&287261EF&0&0000
PowerManagementCapabilities : 
PowerManagementSupported    : 
Service                     : WUDFRd
Status                      : OK
StatusInfo                  : 
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : MyComp
```

Now I'm trying to find the path to the phone to use in my powershell script, which will essentially copy all items it finds to another directory. How do I get a path to the phone, or how to I copy the files without having a path? I've tried using:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Computer\XT1039"
```

Which is the path that is present in the Windows File explorer, but this resolves the path to :

```
'C:\Users\Me\USB\VID_22B8&PID_2E76&MI_00\7&287261EF&0&0000
```

And an ItemNotFoundException is thrown, stating the location does not exit(which it doesn't). Also, My phone is not rooted, in case that is a part of potential solutions

Answer (score 2):

Instead of PowerShell, you might try scripting `ADB` commands to perform the backup.  See [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1912243) for more information.

ADB is part of the Android SDK.

-Edit in response to downvote.  Please review [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/369959/how-do-i-access-mtp-devices-on-the-command-line-in-windows) for more detailed information as to why I answered with scripting `ADB` instead of accessing the MTP device using PowerShell.

Comment: ADB would be useful but i plan to use this script across a number of lap[tops, some of which i am unable to download the Android SDK. Preferably I'd like to be able to do this via Powershell, as its the common technology across the computers I'll be using

Comment: You can migrate the folder containing ADB.exe across laptops/computers.  ADB could be placed in a network folder and accessed that way, if that is at all possible.

Comment: @Downvote, care to explain the reason for the down vote?  Anonymous down voting does not contribute anything useful to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Use this app: https://www.mtpdrive.com/download.html. It maps the phone to an actual drive that can be accessed by the Windows Command Line. The trial version allows the transfer of 30 files. I've tried the trial version on Windows 11 and it works for me.